# AWS Amplify Graphql Mutations - Batch Delete Join Table Item When Original Item Is Deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Category: `API.graphql` mutation

Amplify Version: 8.0.1

Service: `AppSync`

**Research**

I've come across [this documentation](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/443) that notes batch is not supported, and thus requires a custom resolver.

I've also come across [this feature request](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/273) for cascading delete with DynamoDB Streams and Lambda.

I see [there is an example](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/examples-and-solutions/#batch-put-custom-resolver) for a batch put custom resolver.

**Problem:**

There is a `@model` for `JobListing`, and one for `Image` within the Amplify Graphql Schema. They have a `ManyToMany` Relationship. When I delete an `Image` record from DynamoDB, all `JobListingImage` records for that image need to be deleted as well.

I've considered looping through the `JobListingImage` records, but there could be a possiblity where there are 100,000 records to query and then delete.

**Code Snippet of failed attempt**

```
   const handleDelete = async (id, name) => {
     try {
       await API.graphql({
         query: deleteJobListingImages,
         variables: {
           input: {
             imageID: id,
             imageemployerID: Auth.user.attributes["custom:id"],
           },
         },
         authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
       });
       await Storage.remove(name, {
         level: "protected",
       });
       await API.graphql({
         query: deleteImage,
         variables: {
           input: {
             id: id,
             employerID: Auth.user.attributes["custom:id"],
           },
         },
         authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
       });  
     } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);

     }
   };
```

**Question**

How do I delete all the `JobListingImages` that refer to the `Image` id I am deleting?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. Your best call is to use Query followed by BatchWrite to delete entries

Comment: How would you do it on the backend? @karjan